# Can I say I am wondering what the most interesting part of your day was?

Tags: grammar

Can I say

> I am wondering what the most interesting part of your day was?

I have used an online grammar check and it says the question has no errors, but I still think it sounds wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it sounds wrong? Note that that sentence wouldn't normally have a question mark at the end.

Comment: I think "I wonder what the most interesting part of your day was" would be more correct.

Comment: @userr2684291 - I think it only has a question mark at the end because clare is asking about it.  Clare: it would be much more clear if you used quotation marks or something else, like *Can I say "I am wondering what the most interesting part of your day was"?*

Comment: @stangdon I added that note just in case. Note (sorry) that they used a question mark at the end of their second sentence as well – so who knows.

Answer (score 2):

Your example actually sounds more like a statement than a question

> Q: What are you being so pensive about?
>   A: I am wondering what the most interesting part of your day was.

If you were to ask more of a question, you might use

> What was the most interesting part of your day?  *(wondering is implied)*
>   I was wondering, what was the most interesting part of your day?

Comment: To be pensive. Why about? I agree with your answer, though.

Comment: @Lambie In my imaginary conversation, they have both said their hellos, and then one becomes quiet and thinking, when the other asks while looking directly at the first ***What...about?***", being a question with an *expected answer*, instead of a general "Why so pensive?" which, to me, is less direct, but that's just the scenerio that popped into my head.